# Android DialogFragment shows black parts of screen Sony Xperia U

Tags: android-dialogfragment

I use DialogFragments in my game for some popup information. It works fine on LG Nexus 4 running android 4.2 and it runs fine on the Desire S running 2.3.

It does however not run correctly on a Sony Xperia U (running 4). Here is what happens:

[black spaces under dialogfragment](http://www.ghoti.nl/test/error_dialogfragment_sonyU.png)

It does not place the dialog in the middle of the screen, which happens on all other devices, but it also renders a big black section on my screen below the dialog.

Here is my code:

```
public void ShowMessage(String title, String msg)
{
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("title", title);
    b.putString("msg", msg);
    DialogFragment dialog = new DialogFragment_MsgBox();
    dialog.setArguments(b);
    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "msgbox");
}
```

and

```
public class DialogFragment_MsgBox extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle b = getArguments();
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.SetmsgDialog);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.simpleokdialog);
    if(b.containsKey("title"))
        dialog.setTitle(b.getString("title"));
    else
        dialog.setTitle("Message");
    return dialog;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simpleokdialog, container, false);

    Bundle b = getArguments();
    String msg = "";
    if(b.containsKey("msg"))
    {
        msg = b.getString("msg");
    }

    TextView text = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.bericht);
    text.setText(msg);


    Button iv = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.simpleOK);
    iv.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // When button is clicked, call up to owning activity.
            getDialog().dismiss();
        }
    });

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return v;
}
```

}

and also needed the style i use for the dialogfragment:

```
<style name="SetmsgDialog">
        <item name="android:background">#aac6775c</item> 
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>

        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/setwindowTitleStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
        <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
    </style>
```

What can cause this? any solutions/tips or suggestions to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this finally, it appears that some phones/provider software have different behavior in the standard themes etc. (I have seen this with sony again with text being white with shadow on a white background, very nasty looking, and now again with sony, different behavior) So If you do overload some theme, which you always do when using your own and not fill in all the variables, use all variables to get expected out comes!

I had 'forgotten':

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

for which the sony xperia U uses black with no transparency, while nexus 4 and desire S use transparent color.